# Not sure how to contact, but i found a bug in the web-app search function

Tags: web-applications, spotify

While using the webapp, i found that typing the `%` character, crashes the web-app. If you include any text after, so far its critical from what i found and doesn't allow restarting but you need to close the tab and reopen spotify

Answer (score 0):

They have a bug bounty program : https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/bounty/ on hackerone: https://hackerone.com/spotify